# Where the domain is irrational numbers, could ∀x∃y(x+y∈ℚ) be the disproof of ∀x∀y(x+y∉ℚ)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing

The title really says it all. I am aware that the the negation provided isn't accurate (i.e. the latter statement in negated form would be $\exists x \exists y(x+y\in\Bbb Q))$ and it would suffice to simply provide a counterexample. But is it any less correct to show that for any x there exist a y that disproves the statement? This is implies Universal Generalization - if it's true for every object, it's true for all object: P($c$) for any arbitrary $c \to
∴∀x\text P(x)$

I provided the answer in the title for class and was not awarded points because, in summary, I negated incorrectly and I didn't provide a counterexample. I'll take the hit, I did provide the wrong negated statement, but I extrapolated on the negated statement and proved that by universal generalization we can go from "there exist an $x$" to "for any $x$".

Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

Comment: I assume $x$ and $y$ are irrational numbers because you said the the domain is irrational numbers. If so, it is kind of weird to ask wether $x+y=\mathbb Q$, a set of (infinitely many) numbers…

Comment: Moreover, if the domain is irrational numbers, how do you define the binary function $+$? It does not map numbers within this domain. For example, under the usual definition, $\sqrt 2+(2-\sqrt 2)$ is a rational number.

Comment: By $=$ and $\ne$ did you mean $\in$ and $\notin$?

Comment: I think so. And apart from this, I completely agree with him, except that he should produce a counterexample y for any x.

Comment: lol! Definitely meant ∈ and ∉, not = and ≠. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Well, I made my case and the instructors response was that the proof by counterexample would have been a more elegant proof and that my provided proof used an unnecessary "twist"...as long as they acknowledged the validity of the proof, I'm satisfied lol.

Comment: Were you awarded "full" Points after your Discussion ? @Tbone

Answer (score 1):

> Where the domain is irrational numbers, could ∀x∃y(x+y=ℚ) be the disproof of ∀x∀y(x+y≠ℚ)?

No.  I assume that by 'disproof to a statement' you mean a counterexample to the statement, but just providing some statement $X$ by itself is not a counterexample to a different statement $Y$.

This is because even if the two statements are contrary (i.e. cannot both be true), there is nothing that says that that statement $X$ can possibly be true, and hence that it is possible for $Y$ to be false, and it's the latter that you need to show.

Consider this: Suppose I need to provide a disproof for $\forall x \forall y \ x = y$, and suppose I provide the statement $\forall x \forall y \ x \neq y$. Well, it is true that these two statements are contrary, but the problem is that $\forall x \forall y \ x \neq y$ cannot be made true.

Now, of course you say that $\forall x \exists y(x+y=\mathbb{Q})$ is not self-contradictory, and can be made true. OK, you're right ... but you still haven't *shown* that. And to show that, you need to come up with a concrete model. But note that that model will also be a counterexample to claim $\forall x \forall y(x+y \neq \mathbb{Q})$.  So .. you might as well immediately provide a counterexample.

One more note: you said that you negated incorrectly ... and yes, if you negate a statement and you can show that you can make that negation true, then you have thereby also shown a counterexample to the original statement.  However, you do not need to negate a statement to find a counterexample. As long as your statement is *contrary* to the original statement, and you *show* that your statement can be made true, then you have thereby also shown a counterexample to the original statement.

So: points were correctly taken off if the task was to show a counterexample (which you did not).  But if the instructor thought that you had to negate the original statement and then find a model for that negation in order to find a counterexample, then the instructor was wrong about that. Of course, the instructor *is* in their full right to demand that you first negate the statement as part of the exercise/instructions. So if the instructions were to negate the statement, and then to use that to find a counterexample, then points should be taken off your answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Parenthesis** to make it easy to negate : $ ( \forall x ( \forall y ( x+y \ne ℚ ) ) ) [[ EXP 1 ]] $

**(A)** What is the Correct Negation :

We want to negate it : $ ( \lnot ( \forall x ( \forall y ( x+y \ne ℚ ) ) ) ) $

$ ( \lnot ( \forall x ( \forall y ( x+y \ne ℚ ) ) ) ) \Leftrightarrow  ( \exists x ( \lnot ( \forall y ( x+y \ne ℚ ) ) ) ) $
$ ... \Leftrightarrow ( \exists x ( \exists y ( \lnot ( x+y \ne ℚ ) ) ) ) $
$ ... \Leftrightarrow ( \exists x ( \exists y ( x+y = ℚ ) ) ) [[ EXP 2 ]] $

Hence , this is the Correct Negation.

Here , assuming the "$=$" is "$\in$" , we can see that this will satisfy the condition :
$ ( x = 1+\pi ) $ , $ ( y = 1-\pi ) $
$ ( x+y = 2 \in Q ) $

**(B)** What is wrong with the given wrong negation :

This is not the Correct Negation : $ ( \forall x ( \exists y ( x+y = ℚ ) ) ) [[ EXP 3 ]] $

It says that each & every $x$ must have this negative Property , whereas , it is enough to have even a single $x$ where this negative Property is true.

In the current context , it is indeed true that each & every $x$ has at least one $y$ such that this negative Property is true [[ simply take $ ( y = -x+z ) $  where $z$ is rational ]] but that may not be the case in other contexts , hence we can not try this to get the Correct Negation.

**(C)** Can we check that with the logically equivalent chain ?

Yes , we can negate the given wrong negation $ ( \lnot ( \forall x ( \exists y ( x+y = ℚ ) ) ) ) $ to show that we do not get the original.

$ ( \lnot ( \forall x ( \exists y ( x+y = ℚ ) ) ) ) \Leftrightarrow ( \exists x ( \lnot ( \exists y ( x+y = ℚ ) ) ) ) $
$ ... \Leftrightarrow ( \exists x ( \forall y ( \lnot ( x+y = ℚ ) ) ) ) $
$ ... \Leftrightarrow ( \exists x ( \forall y ( x+y \ne ℚ ) ) ) [[ EXP 4 ]] $

This is not Equivalent to the original $ ( \forall x ( \forall y ( x+y \ne ℚ ) ) ) $
Hence that was not the Correct Negation.

(D) Given that EXP 1 is not true , while EXP 2 is true & very close to EXP3 which is also true & EXP 4 is not true , is there a way to salvage the Situation to complete the Exercise ?

In this context , where we add two irrational numbers , to check whether we get irrational number or rational number , we can use Extra "Domain" knowledge to proceed.

We can try this :
$ EXP 2 \Leftrightarrow \lnot EXP 1 $ ( no Extra "Domain" knowledge ! )
Prove EXP3 ( using Extra "Domain" knowledge ! )
$ EXP 3 \implies EXP 2 $ ( Changing $\forall$ to $\exists$ )
Hence, $ EXP 3 \implies \lnot EXP 1 $

We can not have $ EXP 3 \Leftrightarrow \lnot EXP 1 $

Here , OP did not Prove EXP3 , hence , Instructor is right to Deduct Marks.